# Conan2 with Visual Studio 2022: How to install SFML

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, sfml, conan-2

I'm learning how to use Conan2 with Visual Studio 2022. I have a test project that depends on sfml/2.6.0 and spdlog/1.12.0. Here is my conanfile.py file.

```
class TicTacToeRecipe(ConanFile):
    settings = "os", "compiler", "arch", "build_type"
    requires = "sfml/2.6.0", "spdlog/1.12.0"

    def generate(self):
        ms = MSBuildDeps(self)
        ms.generate()
```

I run the following command to install the dependencies.

```
conan install . --output-folder=./dependencies --build=missing -s build_type=Release -s compiler.cppstd=20
```

It creates a set of .props files, as expected. I added the following line to the.vcxproj file to import conandeps.props to my Visual Studio project.

```
Import Project="..\packages\dependencies\conandeps.props" />
```

But when I try to compile, I get the error shown below.

> error MSB4019: The imported project "D:\Work\repo\TicTacToe\packages\dependencies\conan_minimp3.props" was
> not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration
> "conan_minimp3.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I'm curious why this file was not created when the dependencies were installed. Could someone please tell me what's wrong?

Test project: https://github.com/iamshivprasad/tictactoe

Comment: If I downgrade the SFML version (to 2.5.1), everything is fine. So it appears to be a problem with the SFML 2.6.0 Conan package.